# spring-jdbc: How to manage transactions using namedJdbcTemplate to do CRUD with Oracle db

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

As the following code, I use spring-jdbc to access Oracle db. I use namedJdbcTemplate to update and insert.

Now I want to manage transaction with DatasourceTransactionManager. What can I do to code this?

Dao code:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("svsJdbcTemplate")
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

protected NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(DashboardDaoImpl.class);

@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    namedJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(
            jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
}
```

application-jdbc.xml configuration:

```
<bean id="svsJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="svsDataSource"></property>
</bean>


<!-- JNDI Data Source -->
<bean id="svsDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
<!-- 
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/svsDB" />
 -->
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/svsDB"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
    DataSourceTransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="svsDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spring config file replace

```
<bean id="svsJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="svsDataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

with

```
<bean id="svsJdbcTemplate"   
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">  
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>  
</bean>
```

and in the dao class autowire `svsJdbcTemplate` as follows.

```
@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  svsJdbcTemplate;
```

Now for managing the transactions use the `@Transactional` annotation in the service classes.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer,but if  i want to use programmatic transaction manage , should i use try...catch to manage transaction and whether this changes will impact other methods

Comment: thank you,  but my leader want me to use programmatic transaction manage and i think  i can change the configuration and use programmatic meanwhile